# Comparing a number with a line of power

Tags: analysis, number-theory, inequality

How do you compare which is bigger (or maybe equal), LHS or RHS, in
$$a \sim b_1^{b_2^{.^{.^{.^{b_n}}}}}$$
given $a$ and $b_i$, $1 \leq i \leq n$, are non-negative integers (also could be big)?

The problem is, as I do $\log$ to both side, at some point, say $\log(b_i\log(b_{i-1}\dots\log(b_1)\dots))$ where $1\lt i\lt n$, it returns `nan` as they doesn't exceed $1$ (or even negative) in value.

Comment: Doing $\log$ is a good approach.  If you get nan, you have done too many, though as long as all the $b_i \gt 2$ you should be able to do $n-1$ of them.

Comment: I've been using `log` in base $10$ the whole time. Should I consider using base $2$?

Comment: $\log_{10} x = \log_{10} 2\log_2 x\approx .30103 \log_2 x$  In this scale that is nothing.  I would just take logs until you get to something reasonable, then make the comparison.

Comment: Presumably, the difficulty is that these numbers are too big to fit into whatever calculational engine you are using (otherwise, you would just compute both sides to see which is bigger). So I'm not sure I see how logarithms are going to work. If $a$ is already too big to work with, how will you compute $\log a$? Maybe you should give us an example of the kind of number that's giving you trouble, and tell us what the restrictions on computing are.

Comment: Okay, so $a$ won't be too big, it's at most $64$. But the problem resides in $b$. Let's say $b = \{4,1,64\}$, at LHS, $\log_2(\log_2(\log_2(64)))$ gives me $1.370\dots$, while the RHS gives me $\log_2(64\log_2(1\log_2(4)))$, which is, $6.0$, despite LHS > RHS, as $64 > 4^{1^{64}}$. This shows me that blindly applying $\log$ doesn't returns me the desired truth. I'll try to add some special cases if I finds $0$s or $1$s at the moment.

Comment: Taking the log once gives $1^{64}\log_2(4)$. Taking the log again gives $64\log_2(1) + \log_2(\log_2(4))$, which is not $\log_2(64\log_2(1\log_2(4)))$.

Comment: "blindly applying log" Well, *incorrectly* applying log, blindly or otherwise, won't get you very far. But really what's the difficulty in just calculating $4^{1^{64}}$ and seeing that it's $4$ and then comparing $4$ to $64$ to see which one is bigger?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Oh my god! Bull's eye! Thank you!

Comment: I think it's solved now. Thank you Jimmy for pointing my flawed application of $\log$. @GerryMyerson the problem was $b$ sometimes have huge size as a list, but now it's done.